# Find specific shapes in an image

Tags: image, pattern-matching, image-segmentation

I have the following problem, I'm working with gel electrophoresis images [A][B] which show DNA fragments (appear as white bands). I want to extract them and analyze them (on the right site is a standard of known size and concentration, which can be extrapolate to the other three samples). Each sample is loaded into a lane. One task is to find the lanes (in this case 4) and the other to extract at which position in the picture a DNA band is present.

I have some problems with finding the bands. I tried already several things, e.g. pixel comparison, edge detection, corner detection, template matching, binary image, but all of them give insufficient results especially if the pictures are bad (might be a bad ran, kind of smearing[C]) or if the bands are to close tot each other.

Since I'm not an image expert, could someone drop some keywords what is usually used in such cases? Actually I'm even not sure whether the problem is about image segmentation or pattern recognition?!

Any hints would be highly appreciated (also books for beginners).

Thanks in advance!

[A] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gel_electrophoresis

[B]

[image: DNA gel electrophoresis image]

[C]

[image: DNA gel electrophoresis image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, profile extraction will probably do the trick: take a vertical slice of the image across a lane (assuming you have a rough idea of the position), and average the pixel values on every row of the slice. This will give you a 1D signal where the bands appear as distinct peaks of varying heights.

You can detect the peak locations by looking for local maxima (not so robust here), or better by finding sufficiently long increasing and decreasing signal value sequences.

I would more call this a segmentation problem.

Final hint: the lanes might also be located by analysing the profile obtained by averaging on the columns.

Comment: Sorry, being new here, I am not allowed to post explanatory images

Comment: After experimenting a little, I see that all bands can be detected fairly reliably on this image, except for the "replica" below the topmost band in the third lane.